# How can we show the equality $[SL_2(\mathbb Z): \Gamma_0(N)]=N\prod_{p\mid N}\left(1+\frac1p\right)$?

Tags: modular-forms

If you want to read question directly, please go to down.

Firstly, let's give the definitions of $\Gamma(N)$, $\Gamma_1(N)$ ve $\Gamma_0(N)$: $$\Gamma(N) : = \left \{\left[ \begin{array}{cc}a & b \\c & d \end{array} \right] \in SL_2(\mathbb Z) \; : \;\left[ \begin{array}{cc}a & b \\c & d \end{array} \right]\equiv \left[ \begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{array} \right] \mod N \right \},$$$$\Gamma_1(N) : = \left \{ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}a & b \\c & d \end{array} \right] \in SL_2(\mathbb Z) \; : \;\left[ \begin{array}{cc}a& b \\c & d \end{array} \right] \equiv\left[ \begin{array}{cc}1 & * \\0 & 1 \end{array} \right] \mod N \right \}, $$$$\Gamma_0(N) : = \left \{\left[ \begin{array}{cc}a & b \\c & d \end{array} \right] \in SL_2(\mathbb Z) \; : \;\left[ \begin{array}{cc}a & b \\c & d \end{array} \right]\equiv\left[ \begin{array}{cc}* & * \\0 & * \end{array} \right]\mod N \right \}.$$ 1) Obviously, $$\Gamma(n) \subset \Gamma_1(N)\subset \Gamma_0(N) \subset SL_2(\mathbb Z)$$ satisfies.

2) Let the function $$\Gamma_1(N) \to \mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$$ to be $$\left[ \begin{array}{cc}a & b \\c & d \end{array} \right]  \to b \mod N.$$ Since this onto function is an homomorphism and the kernel is $\Gamma(N)$, we will have  $\Gamma(N) \lhd \Gamma_1(N)$ olur ve $$\Gamma_1(N)/\Gamma(N)\stackrel{\sim}{\to}\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$$ and $$[\Gamma_1(N): \Gamma(N)]=N.$$

3) Let the function $$\Gamma_0(N) \to \big(\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z\big)^*$$ to be  $$\left[ \begin{array}{cc}a & b \\c & d \end{array} \right]  \to d \mod N.$$ Since this onto function is an homomorphism and the kernel is $\Gamma_1(N)$, we will have $\Gamma_1(N) \lhd \Gamma_0(N)$ and $$\Gamma_0(N)/\Gamma_1(N)\stackrel{\sim}{\to}\big(\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z\big)^*$$ and so $$[\Gamma_0(N): \Gamma_1(N)]=\phi(N).$$

**Question:** How can we show the equality  $$[SL_2(\mathbb Z): \Gamma_0(N)]=N\prod_{p\mid N}\left(1+\frac1p\right)?$$

Then this will give us $$[SL_2(\mathbb Z): \Gamma(N)]=N^3\prod_{p\mid N}\left(1-\frac1{p^2}\right).$$

Comment: Any comments, hints or references are appreciated.

Comment: Seems it would be easier to consider the homomorphism from $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ to $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ and note that $\Gamma_0$ is the preimage of the subgroup of upper triangular matrices, so you just need to calculate the index of this subgroup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formula for index of $\Gamma_1(n)$ in SL$_2(\mathbf Z)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328856/formula-for-index-of-gamma-1n-in-sl-2-mathbf-z)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I am agree but not sure how to get the part of (1+1/p) part.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, The answer used that I am asking here. But I am asking how we can find this, not asking the formula.

Comment: @studentforever But this is answered in the duplicate - it is proved in the book of  Kilford, pages $22-24$. Also it is proved in the notes of Alex Youcis (see comment there).

Comment: Another solution is given (at least important hints to it) [here](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/332/mfms.pdf), exercise $4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Alex said I will mail you :) Moreover Kilford used Prop 2.11 in the proof and says we will let you prove this in Exercise 9. This is what I am asking. How can I find the Alex Youcis's notes about this? I check he has a blog but ...

Comment: I actually understand how to calculate the index from Kilford, Thanks.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for your help, it is enough for me. I can handle the rest of it.